# Android - Images are not displayed even though it has been loaded

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I set my imageview `layout width to a fix value` , `my layout height to wrapcontent`.
The images for the imageview are loaded via url. What happened is that , by the time my view is drawn, since the image are not yet loaded, it will only draw the `layout_width` . but by the time the images are already loaded, the height is no longer drawn, thus no image will be displayed. It will only be then displayed if I scroll back and forth because, i guess that is the time the view will be redrawn. Is there a way i can solve this problem? using `invalidate()` did not work. Maybe i did it the wrong way?

i'll just post snippets of my code:
this is the `getView` of **MyAdapter** which extends BaseAdapter:

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    Typeface typeFaceMyriadReg = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), MYRIAD_REG);


    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.shop_list_layout, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtShopName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.txtShopName.setTypeface(typeFaceMyriadReg);
        holder.txtShopDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
        holder.txtShopDesc.setTypeface(typeFaceMyriadReg);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.prof_pic);
        holder.progBar = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_progress);



        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(context.getApplicationContext(), holder.progBar);

    ShopRowItem shopItem = (ShopRowItem) getItem(position);

    holder.txtShopName.setText(shopItem.getShopName());
    holder.txtShopDesc.setText(shopItem.getShopDesc());
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(shopItem.getImageUrl(), holder.imageView);

    return convertView;
}
```

then part of the ImageLoder:

```
  public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView)
{
    imageViews.put(imageView, url);
    Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
    if(bitmap!=null){
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else
    {
        queuePhoto(url, imageView);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
} 

// ...
// ...

    //Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
{
    Bitmap bitmap;
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
    public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p){bitmap=b;photoToLoad=p;}
    public void run()
    {
        if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
            return;
        if(bitmap!=null){

            //should i do recalculations and adjustments here? ? ?

            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }   
        else{
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this issue by placing some loading image in your imageview, till you get your image data from server..

```
public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView)
{
imageViews.put(imageView, url);
Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
if(bitmap!=null){
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
else
{
    queuePhoto(url, imageView);
//add this line of code here.....
    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_image_placeholder);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
}
```